# Программа грузит комп

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Написал свою первую программу на Java, но работает она некорректно. Функционал:

1. Спрашивает слово.
2. Считывает файл, если слово найдено - выводит строку.
3. Если не найдено, записывает слово и перевод.

Программа после завершения или при работе программы начинает писать в файл "null - null" до потери пульса.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws  Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i == 0; ) {
            System.out.println("Enter the word :");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try {
                readFiler(reader.readLine());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Файл не найден");
            }
        }
    }

    public  static   String readFiler(String word) throws  Exception {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            FileReader ret = new FileReader("/home/shoolcs/Desktop/test");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(ret);
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null )  {

                if ((line.indexOf(word) != -1)) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    count++;
                }

            }

            reader.close();
            ret.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No file!");
        }
        if(count==0){
            saveFiler(word);
        }
        return null ;

    }

    private  static   String saveFiler (String wor )  throws  Exception{

        System.out.println("Add word " + wor + " in dinctionary :" );
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String translate ;
            translate = reader.readLine() ;
            FileWriter writerrr = new FileWriter("/home/shoolcs/Desktop/test",true);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(writerrr);
                      writer.write(wor + " - " + translate + "\n");

        writer.close();
        writerrr.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Файл не найден");
        }

        return null;
    }
    }
```

Comment: логично - там бесконечный цикл - `for (int i = 0; i == 0; ) `. А условие выхода не обеспечено.

Comment: Ну я так понимаю, пока слово не введено цикл свою роботу не продолжает , или у него есть какой-то тайминг ?

Comment: У циклов нет таймингов

Comment: А почему тогда это происходит если ничего не вводится ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте переписать метод readFiler() с файла с использованием [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

что-нибудь в духе:

```
String currentLine = null;
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    currentString = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Дополнительные примеры можно найти [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032356/using-scanner-nextline)